# Determine if the given relation is an Equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Determine whether the given relation is an equivalence relation on the set.

$x$ is related to $y$ in the set of real numbers if $|x-y| \leq 3$

So I know to see if a set is an equivalence relation it must be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

I am a little confused how to apply these concepts to the given set. Here is how I went about it. I started by picking random values for $x$ and $y$ such as $x=3$ and $y=2$

Testing for symmetry:

$|3-2| \leq 3$

$1<3$ yes

then $3 \leq |3-2|$

This is false so it is not symmetric thus not an equivalence relation?

Comment: I believe you got a bit confused with what symmetry means. Symmetry in an equivalence relation means that if $x\sim y$, then also $y\sim x$. It has nothing to do with what the conditions for the relation are, which you kind of assumed here. So, if $x\sim y$ that means$|x-y|\leq 3$, if we want to ask about symmetry here, we would need to know whether or not this implies that $y\sim x \Leftrightarrow |y-x|\leq 3$. Again, this has *nothing* to do with changing sides of the inequality. Keep in mind that there doesn't need to be a such short rule for a relation.

Comment: @SomeMathStudent Thank you so much! So in this case the set actually would be symmetric, correct?

Comment: It is, in fact. You can think of the condition as follows: $x\sim y$ means that the distance of $x$ and $y$ is no more than $3$. This is obviously symmetric. However, for an equivalence relation we need a bit more...

Comment: alright. Would you mind helping my through determining if it is an equivalence relation? I know for reflective a=a but what does that entail for this case?

Comment: About reflexivity: $x\sim y$ means that the distance between $x,y$ is less than $3$. Is that fulfilled if $y=x$? For transitivity, consider a geometric approach. If the distance between $x,y$ is $\leq 3$, and $y,z$ is $\leq 3$, does that also mean that $|x-z|\leq 3$?

Answer (score 2):

Reflexivity and symmetry *are* satisfied:

- For all $x$, one has $\,\lvert x-x\rvert=0\le 3$, hence $x$ is related to itself.
- *Symmetry* results from the fact that $\,\lvert x-y\rvert=\lvert y-x\rvert$.
- What doesn't necessarily work is *transitivity*: it suffices to find $x,y,z$ such that $\,\lvert x-y\rvert\le 3$ and $\,\lvert y -z\rvert \le 3$ but nevertheless $\,\lvert x-z\rvert > 3 $. For instance: $x=0,\ y=2$ and $z=4$.

Comment: Sorry can you explain reflexivity again? So I would text that x-x=0 and y-y=0?

Comment: See my completed answer. Is that clearer?

Comment: so for reflexivity you just see if the initial value, in case x satisfies the given statement on its own?

Comment: also for transitivity using your given numbers 0-2 is not greater than 3...

Comment: Oops! Sorry, 'twas a typo. I meant $z=4$ (so $y-z=2$).

Comment: Yeah, I figured that and had a pending edit, nevermind anymore

Comment: Btw, I didn't approve your other modification, because I really wanted to show an example.